# Creating categorical variable of dummies in Python

Tags: python, categorical-data, dummy-data

I am trying to create a categorical variable out of three columns containing only 0 and 1.
They would perfectly match being together a categorical variable - however I cannot find a code merging them to be one:  being a categorical variable labeled "Movement"

```
    CAR BIKE FEET
0   0.0 1.0 0.0
1   0.0 1.0 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 1.0
3   0.0 1.0 0.0
4   0.0 0.0 1.0
... ... ... ...
```

Any thoughts or other ways to create the categorical variables would be appreciated.

EDIT: "Movement" should be an object having the three categorical variables included

Comment: How do you plan on encoding 'Movement'? If you merge those 3 into a single value, "Movement" will always have a value of 1.

Comment: I would like to have "Movement" as a category with the three variables included. 
Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correct, you can use `idxmax` with `axis=1` for rows :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CAR':[0,0,0,0,0],"BIKE":[1,1,0,1,0],"FEET":[0,0,1,0,1]})
df['Movement'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
df

CAR BIKE    FEET    Movement
0   0   1   0   BIKE
1   0   1   0   BIKE
2   0   0   1   FEET
3   0   1   0   BIKE
4   0   0   1   FEET
```

Comment: what if we have `df = pd.DataFrame({'CAR':[0,0,0,0,0,1],"BIKE":[1,1,0,1,0,1],"FEET":[0,0,1,0,1,1]})`  then `df['Movement'] ` doesn't return back `CAR,BIKE,FEET` but It only returns the first one `CAR` . How we can fix this case?